# Analytics reporting API authentication with oAuth2 responds with "Not all scopes are approved."

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I`m using Analytics Reporting API in my project to retrieve amount of users currently surfing my website. Consider following code:

```
gapi.auth2.init({
    'clientId': '<Client_ID>',
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
}).then(function(authData) {
    /*1*/
    return gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=<VIEW_ID>&metrics=rt:activeUsers&dimensions=rt:latitude,rt:longitude'
    });
```

But when i set debugger on the line with /*1*/ and want to investigate what`s inside "authData", in the developer console i see following:

> >JSON.stringify(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn)
>
> >"{"Ab":false,"Aia":{"value":false},"hg":{"hg":[]}}"
>   And inside authData i have following:
>
> >JSON.stringify(a.currentUser)
>
> >"{"Ab":{"El":null,"Zi":null},"Aia":{"value":{"El":null,"Zi":null}},"hg":{"hg":[]}}"

That indicates abscence of authenticated user, i presume.
Furthermore, http response for authentication request returns following error

> >{error: "IMMEDIATE_FAILED", detail: "Not all scopes are approved."}

The question is: what does it mean and where can i approve those scopes by myself or maybe there is somone from Google who should approve scopes for my requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well i acidentally stumbled upon this solution. The reason for scopes to seem unapproved is that the application is not accepted inside an google account as capabke of accessing analytics data (and it's crucial as i use oAuth2 clientID bound to that particular account). So the solution is to allow your project to have access to your account. Sadly there is no such statement in api's docs, nor any example was found also.